# How can I tell if a font isn't supported in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Suppose the user want to use a specific font to render the text in the textblock, are there some way to detect whether the font is support in Siliverlight?

Answer (score 0):

Fonts are supplied by the operating system or ROM for windows phone. Then depending on the silveright version + target operating system, you will be able to select from those supported.

In Silverlight 4, any font on the local computer can be used.

In Silverlight 3, certain Latin and East Asian fonts will work depending on the Operating System. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189010(v=vs.95).aspx#silverlight_fonts

In either case, you can deploy the font with your application to ensure it is rendered correctly (by specifying the font source property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.fontsource(v=vs.95).aspx ).